# How to optimize a query on a model with foreign keys AND many to many field

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

(https://pastebin.com/qCMypxwz) These are my models.

Right now 14 queries are made to get the desired result. Mostly, a query is made to get images associated with each product. Image is many to many field because each product has many images.

```
productList = Variants.objects.select_related('prod_id__category')

            for productName in productList:
                products = dict()
               
                prod_id = productName.id 
                products['id'] = prod_id

                products['category'] = productName.prod_id.category.category_name
                products['prod_name'] = productName.prod_id.prod_name
               
        
                prod_images = list(productName.image.values_list('image_url').distinct())
                image_list = list()
                
                for image in prod_images:     
                    image_list.append(image[0])
                products['image'] = image_list
                price =  productName.price
                products['price'] = price
                createdAt =  productName.createdAt
                products['createdAt'] = createdAt
                productListDict.append(products)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can work with [**`.prefetch_related(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to fetch all `Image`s in a single extra query:

```
variants = Variants.objects.select_related(
    'prod_id__category'
).prefetch_related('image')
```

You thus can then access these with `my_variant.image.all()`, but since that queryset is already prefetched, it will thus not load the `Image`s again.

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `…_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `…_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `product`, instead of <s>`prod_id`</s>.

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PascalCase*, so it should be: `created_at` instead of <s>`createdAt`</s>.

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Variant` instead of <s>`Variants`</s>.

Comment: Thank you this worked. But why is that when I attach distinct() or value_list() after my_variant.image.all() the number queries jump to 15 again but without distinct and value_list it remains 4?